# How to install multiple glibc on fedora

Tags: linux, fedora, software-installation, glibc, node.js

I have Fedora 4 installed on my computer and it has glibc version 2.5.3, but I want to install a software that needs a glibc 2.7+. On the other hand, I have some programs that need this 2.5.3 version. I have three questions regarding this problem:

1. How can I install another glibc on my system and still keep the
   2.5.3 as default
2. How can I pass the address of new glibc to the program that I am
   going to install (is it an option in `./configure`?). The software
   that I am going to install is nodejs.
3. In future, how can I tell my software which glibc to use?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Unix & Linux. Please don't cross post questions across the various stackexchange sites. I see you posted this question as well on Super User. http://superuser.com/questions/590495/how-to-install-multiple-glibc-on-fedora. See here for more info: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823/why-is-cross-posting-wrong-on-an-external-site

Comment: See this Q for some ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/847179/multiple-glibc-libraries-on-a-single-host

Comment: On a side note: Fedora 4 is no more supported since a long time. If your system is online I would strongly suggest to a system with security updates ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is classical sysadmin problem, if I get it right, this tool is just what you need:

[Module](http://modules.sourceforge.net/)

What it does is control environment variables, if you want to load a specific version of `glibc` you need to put it on the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (and ideally remove the other one), same deal with programs and applications.

The environment is controlled by loading and unloading modulefiles, the syntax for those files is explained [here](http://linux.die.net/man/4/modulefile).

Comment: there is no LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable

Comment: That's because you are using only the default paths, if you define `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` with some custom library and compile with that library the compiler will search in the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and the default places (I'm not sure the about the search order)

Answer (score 1):

Whatever needs glibc-2.7 won't run on Fedora 4 (for lack of other libraries, or missing kernel features).

Fedora 4 is now 7 or so years old, out of *any* support for 6 years. Update.

Comment: Nope, I am now running a few programs that use glibc-2.7!!!!

Comment: @emab, update now.